# How to display a structure of a list of another structure?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, realloc

I am working on a small project, in which I have a car structure(year, brand, etc..) and a collection structure that contains cars, how do I display the cars inside a collection?

in my Car.h I defined :

```
struct CarP;
typedef struct CarP * Car;
typedef const struct CarP * constCar;

Car car_createCopy(constCar c); //returns a copied car from c 
void display_car(constCar c);
```

in my Collection.h file I defined :

```
struct CollectionP;
typedef struct CollectionP * Collection;
typedef const struct CollectionP * constCol;
```

and in Collection.c :

```
struct CollectionP{
    int nbCars;
    Car * carList;
}

int getNbCars(constCol c){
    return c -> nbCars;
}

void add_car(Collection c, constCar car){
    int nbCar = getNbCars(c);
    if(nbCar == 0)
        c -> carList = malloc(sizeof(car));
    else{
        c -> carList = realloc(c -> carList,(nbCar+1)*sizeof(car));
        c -> carList[nbCar] = car_createCopy(car);
    }
    c -> nbCars++;
}

void display_col(constCol c){
    int nbCar = getNbCars(c);
    for(int i = 0; i < nbCar; i++)
        display_car(c -> carList[i]);
}
```

after adding some cars to the collection, I try to call the display function, I get only one car with null for brand and different numbers as values for other fields and then the program stops with a segmentation fault error.

Comment: Fyi, hiding pointer types in type aliases (`Car` and `Collection` in this case) does *not* make the code easier to read, understand, or maintain. There are only two cases where pointer type aliasing is legitimately called for: black-box "handle" APIs, and callback function pointer prototyping. Neither appear to be necessary in this code, and I *urge* you to not do that now, or in the future. C programmers want to see asterisks; it's in our nature, and we eat them for breakfast. If a pointer is really a pointer-to-pointer, you want to see that directly.

Comment: @WhozCraig yes I am aware of that, but it's a university project and this is how I have to do it, but I completely understand your idea.

Comment: That being the case, so long as you completely understand your university is promoting terrible habits (not shocking), I'm glad to hear you know better. Such a bad habit. Anyway, that said, look at your *first* car addition logic. How does the first car make it into the collection? All you do is allocate the initial pointer bed; no assignments, etc, thereafter happen. That line `c->carList[nbCar] = car_createCopy(car);` should be *outside* (after) the else block before the increment of `c->nbCars`. Just saying.

Comment: @WhozCraig I feel so stupid.. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong . (see `// HERE` below):

```
void add_car(Collection c, constCar car){
    int nbCar = getNbCars(c);
    if(nbCar == 0)
        c -> carList = malloc(sizeof(car));
    else{
        c -> carList = realloc(c -> carList,(nbCar+1)*sizeof(car));
        c -> carList[nbCar] = car_createCopy(car);  // HERE
    }
    c -> nbCars++;
}
```

That marked line is what is responsible for placing the car copy into the list. but it never executes on the first addition. It should be moved, specifically after, and outside, the `else` block.

```
void add_car(Collection c, constCar car){
    int nbCar = getNbCars(c);
    if(nbCar == 0)
        c -> carList = malloc(sizeof(car));
    else{
        c -> carList = realloc(c -> carList,(nbCar+1)*sizeof(car));
    }
    c -> carList[nbCar] = car_createCopy(car);  // FIXED
    c -> nbCars++;
}
```

That said, there are a ton of places in this that need error checking, and your usage of `realloc` should be going through a temporary pointer, lest you lose your allocated list to a faulty `NULL` result. But the core of your problem is as i showed above.